# How can I bind buttons and dialog boxes using tkinter?

Tags: python, user-interface, button, tkinter, bind

I'm trying to create a Python GUI with tkinter. Can anyone please advise how I can do the following:

1. Place the Open button on the top right hand side of my screen
2. How can I combine my "Open" button with opening a dialog box where a user can choose which file to open?
3. Place the Label under the Open button - all I can do is place them at the top of the root or right of the root
4. Do I need to use a canvas as well as a frame..?
5. How to send/display mouseclicks (x,y co-ordinates) to the label instead of my console?

My code is as follows:

```
from tkinter import *

def clicks(event):                          
    print(event.x, event.y)                 
    xy_coord = "x=%d y=%d" % (event.x, event.y)
    return xy_coord

myroot = Tk()                               

label = Label(myroot, text="Co-ord: ", fg="black")  
label.pack(side=TOP)                        

myFilename = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes = ( ("how code files", "*.hc"), ("All Files", "*.*") ) ) 
print(myFilename)

button = Button(myroot, text="Open file: ", fg="Blue") 
button.bind("<Button>", click)
button.pack(side=RIGHT, padx=5, pady=5)     

frame = Frame(myroot, bg="Grey", width=300, height=300) 
frame.bind("<Button>", clicks)              
frame.pack(expand=YES, fill=BOTH)           

myroot.mainloop()
```

Comment: I would suggest to open a separate question for each of your problems, but before doing that, you may want to search SO for answers, some of what you are asking has been asked and answered before.

Comment: What Reblochon said. But in the mean time... you can easily control the placement of widgets by using the `.grid` method instead of `.pack`. And you don't need a Canvas.

Comment: All of what you ask is clearly documented, is covered in one or more tkinter tutorials, and/or has plenty of examples here on stackoverflow. Stackoverflow isn't a code writing service. You're expected to do the work, and then ask _specific_ questions that can't be answered by looking at other answers or by reading documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I advice you to use Grid insted of pack which will give you more control over your design. In Grid, you can add your button to left column (I don't know how many columns you will have. If you have three columns you will add your button to third column) and you may use

   ```
   openButton.grid(column=3, sticky=E)
   ```

which means your button will stick to the east side of your column. You can also use N, E, W, S or combinations like EW to expand your button.

2. Write a event for open button to oepn a dialog for choosing the file.

   ```
   def browse(event):
       myFilename = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes = ( ("how code files", "*.hc"), ("All Files", "*.*") ) )

   openButton.bind("<Button-1>", browse)
   ```

After that you can use the path of your file, myFilename to open the file.

3. Again if you use Grid system, you can place open button to first row and third column and label to second row and third column. Code will be similar to this

   ```
   openButton.grid(row=1, column=3 sticky=E)

   label = Label(myroot).grid(row=2, column=3 sticky=E)
   ```
4. You don't need a canvas unless you want to draw something.
5. you can use `.config` for updating a label's text in Tkinter.

   ```
   def clicks(event):                                         
       xy_coord = "x=%d y=%d" % (event.x, event.y)
       label.config(text= xy_coord)
   ```

Comment: Tesekkur Ederim Mustafa & Kiitos Antti!